# Guide to create magento module

Tags: forms, magento, module, admin

I am new to magento , and i have a knowledge of magento templates  and theme , now i want to **learn** the **magento core** , 
I want to learn that how can i create my **custom form in admin and stores its data in table and fetch that data on frontend .**
For this i have done so much search on  web but they all are so confusive 
can anybody suggest me the best way to this or please provide me the good site references .

> custom form in admin and stores its data in table and fetch that data
>   on frontend

Thanks

Comment: Hello check this link may be help you http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_an_admin_form_module

Answer (score 1):

You can use a module creator and see what files it generates. 
I recommend these:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html - this is mine that's why I recommend it first. You can create modules and entities more or less like creating tables in phpmyadmin.
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modulecreator.html - this is a minimalist one but very good to start with.
- http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ - this is kind of complex but it has the advantage of being online so you don't have to install anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want learn Magento core try bellow link. I always recommend this.

**[CLICK ME](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento)**

Then if you feel that you can understand magento core then refer above post that @Marius mentioned.  Those are module creators. Create some dummy modules, download and  install it, refer that codes..Thats it..!Now you are a Magento DEVELOPER..!